# Select Inner Join do que não está na outra tabela

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho duas tabelas, `Anuidades` e `Pagamentos`.

Dessas anuidades é preciso selecionar os dados das `Anuidades` que ainda não foram pagas.

**Tabela `Anuidades`**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Tabela `Pagamentos`**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para retornar os dados das anuidades que tinham sido pagas usei a seguinte *query*:

```
SELECT * 
FROM anuidades
INNER JOIN pagamentos ON anuidades.Id = pagamentos.idAnuidade
WHERE pagamentos.idMinistro = 1
```

e ele retornou corretamente:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém quando tento selecionar as anuidades que não tem registro na tabela de pagamentos não consigo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há mais de uma maneira de fazer este select, segue algumas formas:

**LEFT OUTER JOIN**

```
SELECT * FROM ANUIDADES
LEFT JOIN PAGAMENTOS 
    ON ANUIDADES.Id = PAGAMENTOS.idAnuidade
WHERE PAGAMENTOS.idAnuidade IS NULL
```

**NOT EXISTS**

```
SELECT * FROM ANUIDADES
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT NULL FROM PAGAMENTOS
                WHERE   PAGAMENTOS.IDMINISTRO = 1
                AND     PAGAMENTOS.IDANUIDADE = ANUIDADES.ID)
```

**NOT IN**

```
SELECT * FROM ANUIDADES
WHERE ANUIDADES.ID NOT IN (
                        SELECT IDANUIDADE FROM PAGAMENTOS
                        WHERE IDMINISTRO = 1)
```

Obs: LEFT JOIN / IS NULL e NOT EXISTS são semanticamente equivalentes, enquanto NOT IN não é.

Comment: Show!! O primeiro do LEFT OUTER JOIN retornou vazio, mas o outros dois, NOT EXISTS e NOT IN funcionaram perfeitamente!! Muito obrigado!!

Comment: Que bom que funcionou. Entretanto o LEFT OUTER JOIN deveria funcionar também, simulei com as mesmas tabelas que você forneceu e retornou igual aos outros 2 exemplos. Lembre-se que no LEFT OUTER JOIN não podes colocar `WHERE/AND   PAGAMENTOS.IDMINISTRO = 1` pois com isso vai retornar vazio mesmo.

Answer (score 5):

Tenta assim:

```
SELECT anuidades.* 
FROM anuidades
LEFT JOIN pagamentos ON anuidades.Id = pagamentos.idAnuidade
WHERE pagamentos.idMinistro = 1
AND pagamentos.idAnuidade Is null
```

Comment: Não deu certo, ele retorna vazio =/